# How to convert JSON to KSQL STRUCT formatting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ksqldb

Is there a way to convert a JSON format such as:

```
{
    "fruit": "apple",
    "taste": 
    {
        "sweetness": "5",
        "bitterness": "1",
        "sourness": "1"
    }
}
```

into KSQL STRUCTs such as:

```
(
    fruit VARCHAR, \
    taste STRUCT \
    < \
        sweetness VARCHAR, \      
        bitterness VARCHAR, \
        sourness VARCHAR \
    > \
)
```

without manually looping through the JSON and programmatically adding commas and printing brackets?  Perhaps a Javascript function or library?  I'm fine with defaulting all the types into VARCHAR.

Comment: It seems like a pretty specific / niche thing to do, so I doubt there is much library support. Is there any particular reason you don't want to do the conversion yourself? It also seems quite straight-forward.

Comment: I was curious because it seemed like a type -> type change with some nested possibilities so I wanted to check before I reinvent the wheel.  The JSONs I will be converting will be long, but since it's programmatic it shouldn't be a big issue as you say.  I think I will end up writing it, but I wanted to ask just in case.

Comment: @QuantumRich just to confirm - you're wanting a way to generate the DDL for KSQL, from a given JSON message?

Comment: Yes thats right